# Is it possible to determine when a NTFS partition was created?

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, date, timestamp

We have a client where it would be very useful to determine WHEN a drive was a initialized or an NTFS partition created.  Is there a timestamp value somewhere?  If anyone could shed any advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-slashp

Comment: Just an idea but could you reverse the volume UUID computation to get a date/time?  (I don't know how the UUID is generated so it would take some research to find out and it may not be possible at all.)

Comment: @ChrisNava: The unique ID used in NTFS is not a 128-bit UUID but a random 64-bit number. (Besides, modern systems do not generate type 1 time-based UUIDs either; type 4 random-based UUIDs are preferred for privacy. If it *were* a type 1 UUID, though, then there would not be any computation to reverse; the timestamp is stored in plain sight.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Yes.  You can even do it over a LAN.

The CIFS transaction is `TRANS2_QFSINFO` and the information level is [`SMB_QUERY_FS_VOLUME_INFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff470105%28v=prot.13%29.aspx).  The native Windows NT API function for querying a volume's creation time is [`ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff567070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which yields a [`FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff540287%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data structure (almost identical to the CIFS one, note) when asked for the `FileFsVolumeInformation` class of information.  Testing that this query works is part of the IFS tester that Microsoft supplies to driver developers.

Interestingly, no-one appears to have written a handy utility that just queries a volume and prints its creation timestamp in human readable form.<sup>1</sup>  The nearest that you are going to get as far as I can tell is to crank up SysInternals' `procmon` tool and look for the volume information queries streaming by.  Perhaps someone reading this will be inspired to create an enhanced `vol` command.

Yes, the volume creation timestamp *is* properly initialized, and isn't just set to zero or some other constant.  I haven't checked, but my educated guess for the storage location of this information is the `$STANDARD_INFORMATION` attribute of the `$Volume` MFT entry.  I can think of three other possible places, but that's the most logical one.

---

<sup>1</sup>`grawity`'s utility just needs a little more polish, including simple uses of `FileTimeToSystemTime()` and `GetTimeFormat()`, to make it usable for end-users that cannot decode Win32 timestamps in their heads.  ☺

Comment: Wow, I give you a +1 for this answer because it was exactly what I was looking for.  Unfortunately, I am not a Win32 API programmer with knowledge of the system internals and was looking for a quick solution.  Good thought with the procmon.  Thanks though!!!

Comment: Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/1596864)? (ugly code warning)

Answer (score 8):

There is no "volume creation date" that I know of built-in to NTFS. However, you should be able to approximate the creation date quite closely by looking at the creation date of the `System Volume Information` directory in the root of the volume.

Comment: This gives me a very good approximation.  Thank you for your quick response!  Now I know who to blame for the drive not being included in our backups :).

Answer (score 0):

This is exposed somewhere.  If you boot up a Windows XP CD and access the recovery console, the version of chkdsk there will print out the volume creation date after it is finished running.