# Is it possible to get timestamp when is HDD formated?

Tags: forensics, data-recovery

I have wondering is it possible to determine when is HDD formated?
It was formated with GParted from live linux. Previously, Windows was installed and filesystem was NTFS. Thanks

Comment: This depends on the filesystem. Was it formatted to NTFS again? Was it formatted to a Linux filesystem like ext4 or btrfs?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you formatted it to. Simply partitioning a disk does not leave any timestamps. When you format it however, you are creating a new filesystem on a given partition. Whether or not the creation date is recorded depends on the specific filesystem. As you didn't say what filesystem you formatted it to, I'll answer for the most popular filesystem for Windows, OSX, and Linux.

### Linux ext4

This is a modern filesystem supported by most major Linux distributions. It is one of the most popular filesystems in use. According to the [ext4 disk layout](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#The_Super_Block), the superblock contains a 32-bit timestamp, `s_mkfs_time`, holding the number of seconds since the epoch when the filesystem was created. To get the date of creation of an ext4 filesystem, you can run the debugging [`tune2fs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html) command as root, in the form of `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1`, with the device replaced with the particular partition you want to check. This will output a lot of debugging information. Look for the field `Filesystem created`.

### OS X HFS+

HFS+ is the standard filesystem on Mac OS X and many other Apple devices. The volume header contains the [`createDate`](https://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/HFSPLUS/hexdumps/hfsplus_volume_header.html#createDate) field, which specifies when the volume was first created. While I am not particularly familiar with OS X, a quick search showed a command called [`hfsdebug`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616020646/http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/). This command takes the filesystem volume as an argument and outputs a bunch of debugging information. Look for the field `createDate`, which should give you the date of filesystem creation.

### Windows NTFS

NTFS is the filesystem used by most Windows computers. The date the filesystem was created is stored in [`FILE_FS_VOLUME_INFORMATION`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_fs_volume_information). This data structure can be retrieved using the native Windows NT API [`ZwQueryVolumeInformationFile()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryvolumeinformationfile). According to a [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/377339/is-it-possible-to-determine-when-a-ntfs-partition-was-created/377379#377379), there is no handy utility to retrieve this information, but the SysInternals `procmon` utility may allow you to get this information. A [simple program](https://gist.github.com/grawity/1596864) was created in response to that superuser question, which be useful.

Unlike Linux and other Unix-like systems, Windows does not store timestamps in the form of seconds since the epoch (00:00:00 on January 1, 1970). Rather, time on Windows systems is represented as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since the beginning of the year 1601.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I didn't create new filesystem after deleting previous partitions. I just deleted all partitions via Gparted. HDD now contains only unallocated data. So, if I understand correctly, it is not possible to determine when is partition deleted? Thanks!

Comment: That is correct. If you did not create a new filesystem (that is what formatting is), then there is no timestamp you can use to determine when you did this.