# Is there a way to find out when was my USB flash drive was last updated or formatted?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive

I feel someone has formatted my USB flash drive and there were some files inside it, is there a way I can check when was my USB flash drive formatted? I am using Windows.

I used the USB flash drive around 7 months ago on a Linux (Ubuntu) system and the formatting supposedly happened on a Windows system 2-4 days ago but I want to confirm the specific date and time.

Comment: What is the file-system format of the flash drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to get timestamp when is HDD formated?](https://superuser.com/questions/1294102/is-it-possible-to-get-timestamp-when-is-hdd-formated)

Comment: A drive is a drive in this sense.  It doesn't matter if it is SSD, HDD, USB flash.. or anything else.